# Create dynamic ggvis chart from uploaded file in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rcharts, ggvis

I am trying to use Shiny and ggvis to:

1) upload a data set

2) have the user select 2 columns (x, y)

3) return a ggvis plot displaying (x, y) from the uploaded data set

I've tried editing the examples from the Shiny [Interactivity](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html) page as well as the [movie explorer](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/movie-explorer.html) example.  However, no chart is displayed.

I think my issue is around uploading the data set, but I don't know where to begin... Any suggestions?

Note - I've also tried this using rCharts, but I run into similar problems where no chart is displayed.

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

fileHeaderNames <- reactive({

  infile <- input$datfile

  if(is.null(infile))
    return(NULL)

  d <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = T)
  return(names(d))

})

# dynamic variable names
observe({

  updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = fileHeaderNames())
  updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = fileHeaderNames())

}) # end observe

  # uploading data set
  theData <- reactive({ 

    validate(
       need(input$datfile != "", "Please upload a file")
    )

    infile <- input$datfile
    dat <- read.csv(infile$datapath, 
                    header = T,
                    stringsAsFactors = F)

    if(is.null(infile)) return(NULL)

    data.frame(x = dat[, input$x],
               y = dat[, input$y])

    })

  # A simple visualisation. In shiny apps, need to register observers
  # and tell shiny where to put the controls
  theData %>%
    ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(ggvis)
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  div(),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput('datfile', ''),
    selectInput('x', 'x:' ,'x'),
    selectInput('y', 'y:', 'y'),
    uiOutput("plot_ui")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("plot")
  )
))
```

Comment: I can get this to work with googleVis, but I would like to use some features that are not available within that package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an attempt, I added a couple of reactive blocks to get the names that should be added on the plot axis.

A trick you can use is to create a filtered dataframe that has two columns `x` and `y` and that changes when the user changes the values in the `selectInput`. You can then tell `ggvis` to plot `x` and `y` from that filtered dataframe and the plot will be interactive.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  #load the data when the user inputs a file
  theData <- reactive({
    infile <- input$datfile        
    if(is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)        
    d <- read.csv(infile$datapath, header = T)
    d        
  })



  # dynamic variable names
  observe({
    data<-theData()
    updateSelectInput(session, 'x', choices = names(data))
    updateSelectInput(session, 'y', choices = names(data))

  }) # end observe

  #gets the y variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  yVarName<-reactive({
    input$y
  })

 #gets the x variable name, will be used to change the plot legends
  xVarName<-reactive({
    input$x
  })

  #make the filteredData frame

  filteredData<-reactive({
    data<-isolate(theData())
    #if there is no input, make a dummy dataframe
    if(input$x=="x" && input$y=="y"){
      if(is.null(data)){
        data<-data.frame(x=0,y=0)
      }
    }else{
      data<-data[,c(input$x,input$y)]
      names(data)<-c("x","y")
    }
    data
  })

  #plot the ggvis plot in a reactive block so that it changes with filteredData
  vis<-reactive({
    plotData<-filteredData()
    plotData %>%
    ggvis(~x, ~y) %>%
    layer_points() %>%
    add_axis("y", title = yVarName()) %>%
    add_axis("x", title = xVarName()) %>%
    add_tooltip(function(df) format(sqrt(df$x),digits=2))
  })
    vis%>%bind_shiny("plot", "plot_ui")

})
```

EDIT: added tooltips.

Comment: Hey @NicE, thanks so much for helping me out on this one!  I never thought to put `data <- theData()` inside of the `observe` statement.  The last thing I wanna do hear is add tooltips, I'm thinking it will work, but I may have to reach out if I can't.  :p  Thanks again!

Comment: can you update this to demonstrate how tooltips would work?  I am running into errors adding tooltips and editing the data.  For instance, if I wanted to calculate the `sqrt(x)` instead of `x`, it doesn't work.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I added a tooltip line in the ggvis plot, when you hover over a point, you'll get a tooltip with the sqrt of the x value. The format is just to keep it to two digits.

Comment: I guess it's worth to emphasize that the empty dummy data.frame is crucial, otherwise the app will crash before the you had a chance to upload anything because NULL can't be processed by Vega (under the hood of ggvis).