# shiny / leaflet: Mapping data from uploaded file error: addCircleMarkers requires numeric longitude/latitude values

Tags: shiny, leaflet, coordinates, observers

I'm trying to create somethning in Shiny where a file can be uploaded, that include the coordinates. In the end I want to include more variable choices but for now I have a very simple set-up that also includes my problem: I can't get shiny to use the uploaded coordinates, and I'm possibly missing something like an oserver/proxy. This is what I have so far:

UI

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = "style.css",


                  titlePanel("Data Mapping\n"),
                  tabsetPanel(
                    tabPanel(h4("Upload File"),
                             titlePanel(h5("Upload your data here:")),
                             sidebarLayout(
                               sidebarPanel(
                                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                                           accept=c('text/csv', 
                                                    'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                                                    '.csv')),

                                 # added interface for uploading data from
                                 # http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/file-upload.html
                                 tags$br(),
                                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                              c(Comma=',',
                                                Semicolon=';',
                                                Tab='\t'),
                                              ','),
                                 radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                              c(None='',
                                                'Double Quote'='"',
                                                'Single Quote'="'"),
                                              '"')

                               ),
                               mainPanel(
                                 tableOutput('contents')
                               )
                             )
                    ),
                    tabPanel(h4("Data Map"), 
                             leafletOutput("leafmap", width = 2000, height = 850),
                             pageWithSidebar(    
                               headerPanel(''),
                               absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                                             draggable = TRUE, top = "20%", left = "auto", right = 40, bottom = "auto",
                                             width = 100, height = 600, offset = 15, style='width: 350px; height: 400px;opacity: 0.8;padding:20px;',

                                             # "Empty inputs" - they will be updated after the data is uploaded
                                             selectInput('xcol', 'Longitude',  "", selected = ""),
                                             selectInput('ycol', 'Latitude',  "", selected = ""),
                                             selectInput('Varchoice', 'Variable', "", selected = "")

                               ),

                               mainPanel(
                                 plotOutput('MyPlot')
                               )
                             )
                    ),


                    navbarPage(title = div( "XXX"), position = "fixed-top",
                               windowTitle = "Pilot", theme = shinytheme("flatly"), tags$style(HTML(".datepicker {z-index:99999 !important;}"))

                    )
                  )
))
```

Server

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {




  mydata<-reactive({ 
    req(input$file1)
    inFile <- input$file1 
    if(is.null(inFile)){return()}
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
             quote = input$quote)
  })


  output$contents <- renderTable({
    mydata()
  })


  observe({  
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'xcol', label = 'Longitude',
                      choices = names(mydata()))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = 'ycol', label = 'Latitude',
                      choices = names(mydata()))

  })

  output$leafmap <- renderLeaflet({
    mydata<-mydata()


    leaflet(data=mydata()) %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkers(~input$xcol, ~input$ycol)
  })


})
```

To see if everything works I'm using a textfile with the following data:

```
example.df<-data.frame(
  Season = c("summer", "summer","summer","summer","summer","winter","winter","winter","winter","winter"),
  Value = c(10, 30, 40, 70, 60, 80, 90, 45, 78, 50),
  Country = c("NL", "AR",   "IT",   "FI",   "IN", "NL", "AR",   "IT",   "FI",   "IN"),
  YCOR = c(52.282458,-34.042788,    43.26699,   -17.829055, -4.880873,52.282458,-34.042788, 43.26699,   -17.829055, -4.880873),
  XCOR = c(4.981905,    -63.241606, 11.892454,  178.01177,  120.163872, 4.981905,   -63.241606, 11.892454,  178.01177,  120.163872))
```

The Error that I get is:

```
> Warning: Error in validateCoords: addCircleMarkers requires numeric
> longitude/latitude values Stack trace (innermost first):
>     89: validateCoords
>     88: derivePoints
>     87: addCircleMarkers
>     86: function_list[[k]]
>     85: withVisible
>     84: freduce
>     83: _fseq
>     82: eval
>     81: eval
>     80: withVisible
>     79: %>%
>     78: func [C:\Users\Documents\Projects/server.R#33]
>     77: origRenderFunc
>     76: output$leafmap
>      1: runApp
```

Comment: this `addCircleMarkers(~input$xcol, ~input$ycol)` should be replaced with `addCircleMarkers(~XCOR, ~YCOR)` your dataset is already reactive and you must use your x and y to plot the map. You can use for example `input$Season` to color or size your points.

Comment: @MLavoie Thank you for your answer! The problem is that I want it as flexible that any file can be uploaded with different file names. I did just find the answer from another post
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176944/create-dynamic-ggvis-chart-from-uploaded-file-in-shiny]

Comment: ggvis is different. Any variables can be plotted. lat and long in leaflet need to be numerical.

Comment: True, but I kept keeping error messages that indicated that my selected input wasn't correct for the leaflet part. So I took (and changed) the filteredData(), yVarName, xVarName part from the other answer to create a reactive dataframe and used that to enter in leaflet:

dat2<-filteredData()
leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%
      addCircleMarkerslng=dat2$x, lat=dat2$y)

and that works

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Wondering why this question has not been answered for almost four years... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780367/read-in-longitude-and-latitude-as-numeric-data-to-modules-of-shiny-leaflet-app